# object/subject: which is the right word to use here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The fight was the "object" of massive fan attention.

The fight was the "subject" of massive fan attention.

Which is the correct way to say the fight got a lot of attention between the given choices? The internet tells me it's the first one.

Answer (score 1):

As you saw from the Internet, people usually pay attention to an "object". [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subject%20of%20attention%2Cobject%20of%20attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubject%20of%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobject%20of%20attention%3B%2Cc0) is a comparison from Google ngrams.

"Subject" more often refers to a topic of discussion, study, etc. For example, if two people are debating, then we might ask about the "subject" of their debate. [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subject%20of%20debate%2Cobject%20of%20debate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubject%20of%20debate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobject%20of%20debate%3B%2Cc0) is another comparison.

There can be overlap. For example, a particular plant or animal species might be either the "object" or the "subject" of a biologist's study.

Comment: I think your first NGram is misleading. It picks up a large number of "similar, but not identical" usages that skew the pattern

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can you give some examples of similar but not identical phrases that might skew the result? If it seems to be significant, then I'll try to find a better example.

Comment: Look at the search strings used in ***my*** NGram charts. It's a bit complicated to explain exactly which contexts are more likely to use "object" instead of "subject" here, so I won't bother trying here in this comment. But there's no doubt that the specific context of *being the **subject/object** of [qualifier] **attention*** significantly favours ***subject*** today, even though ***object*** was more common a couple of centuries ago. And for near-synonymous ***debate***, the preference is overwhelming, and always was.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see what you mean. However, there must some nuance concerning the qualifier, because replacing "much" with "my", for example, favors "object" instead of "subject": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=object+of+my+attention%2Csubject+of+my+attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobject%20of%20my%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubject%20of%20my%20attention%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @FumbleFingers OP wrote "massive", but unfortunately ngrams doesn't seem to have enough data for "object/subject of massive attention".

Comment: Erm... that's why I chose to chart usage for the far more common ***much** attention*. Surely you're not implying it makes any difference whether we're talking about ["semantically sloppy"] ***massive*** or ***much*** attention, or whether or not the specific ***source*** of the attention (***fan[s]***, here) is explicitly given?

Comment: I think your *object of my attention* chart is probably influenced by [*object of my **affections***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=object+of+my+affections%2Csubject+of+my+affections%2Cobject+of+my+attention%2Csubject+of+my+attention&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), which almost ***never*** occurs with ***subject***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I do think that the modifier ("massive", "much", etc.) matters. I tried a couple of other phrases: "object/subject of constant attention" (neither seems to be especially favored) and "object/subject of everyone's attention" ("object" is heavily favored). I'm not sure whether there is a rule or general pattern, though.

Comment: I think the usage difference is mainly concerned with whether the "attention, debate, criticism, etc." is thought of as something ***pre-existing***.  For the most part, "public attention" exists as part of the backdrop of society, which can be focused on one "subject" or another ("subject[ed]" to public scrutiny, never "objected"). OP's fans exist, and will always be paying attention to *something*. With an ***object*** of attention / affection, there might not be any attention / affection around at all, were it not for the specific thing ***causing*** it (rather than ***attracting*** it).

Comment: But this level of analysis is way beyond anything relevant to the average person who simply wants to get by in English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree; the difference can be pretty subtle.

Answer (score 1):

This is an area where there's been [significant change over time...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20subject%20of%20much%20attention%2Cthe%20object%20of%20much%20attention&year_start=1880&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20subject%20of%20much%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20object%20of%20much%20attention%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20subject%20of%20much%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20object%20of%20much%20attention%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

But actually, using "object" instead of "subject" in such contexts was always a bit odd, given that we [never had any significant tendency to do that with ***debate***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20subject%20of%20much%20debate%2Can%20object%20of%20much%20debate&year_start=1880&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20subject%20of%20much%20debate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20object%20of%20much%20debate%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20subject%20of%20much%20debate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20object%20of%20much%20debate%3B%2Cc0), which is near-synonymous in this context...

[image]

Comment: "object of much attention" sounds similar to "object of desire", which is still idiomatic.

Comment: I didn't think of it at the time, but you're quite right. As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+subject+of+debate%2Ca+subject+of+much+desire%2Can+object+of+much+desire%2Ca+subject+of+desire%2Can+object+of+desire&year_start=1880&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20subject%20of%20debate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20object%20of%20much%20desire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20subject%20of%20desire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20object%20of%20desire%3B%2Cc0) shows, it's usually ***object** of desire*, but ***subject** of debate* (and ***...much** desire* is "uncommon").